# Cannot read data in Firebase Database as list

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The data in firebase is like the following

[image: data image here]

I want to get the data tagged as userId as list or an array.

my method is:

```
public static void writePostToFriends(final String userId, final String userName, final String title, final String body, final String authorPhoto){
    DatabaseReference mpostRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("social/user/"+userId+"/friends");
    mpostRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            GenericTypeIndicator<List<Friends>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<Friends>>() {};
            List<Friends> mFriends = dataSnapshot.getValue(t);
            long j = mFriends.size();
            for (long i = 0; i == j; i++){
                Friends mReadFriends = dataSnapshot.getValue(Friends.class);
                String getUid = mReadFriends.userID;
                writeNewPost(getUid, userId, userName, title, body, authorPhoto);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

but when it try to read it gives this error -

> Process: com.evolutionstudios.atmiyo, PID: 19506
>                                                                                com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanp.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanp.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanp.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.evolutionstudios.atmiyo.Utils.NotificationHelper$1.onDataChange(NotificationHelper.java:40)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzakg.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzalg.zzcxk(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzalj$1.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)

can anyone help me to figure out how to get the userID in the data as array or as a list?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The error message contains the gist of it:

> Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap

If you look at your database, you see a collection of keys+values. In Java that translates to a `Map` and not to a `List`.

If you're only interested in the values, you need to handle the conversion from the `Map` to the `List` in your code:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Friends>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Friends>>() {};
    Map<String, Friends> map = dataSnapshot.getValue(t);

    // get the values from map.values();
```

Or simpler:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    List<Friends> list = new ArrayList<Friends>();
    for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        list.add(child.getValue(Friends.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: the code last line says required: list but found collections

Comment: Ah... that could be. Feel free to edit. The important bit of the answer is that `snapshot.getValue()` is a `Map` and not a `List`. I added a snippet that makes this even simpler.

Comment: the simplified one i understood thanx