# Firebase node delete causes NullPointerException

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm attempting to read from Firebase with the following code:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    long value=dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
    Log.d(TAG,"no of children: "+value);

    GenericTypeIndicator<List<POI>> genericTypeIndicator =new GenericTypeIndicator<List<POI>>(){};

    List<POI> poiList=dataSnapshot.getValue(genericTypeIndicator);

    for(int i=0;i<poiList.size();i++){
        Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: content"+ poiList.get(i).getName());
    }
}
```

This works fine when my test data includes the original 4 nodes.  However, when I go into the Firebase console and manually delete a node, my app crashes.  The weird thing is that `dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()` returns 3...so it appears to recognize the delete, but `dataSnapshot.getValue(genericTypeIndicator)` returns a list with a size of 4, with the deleted item now null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your comment is not helpful.  If you're referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501805/delete-an-item-from-firebase-without-crashing-the-app), that is not related to my question.  In that question the entire dataSnapshot is null, while in my case only one of the children is null.  None of the Google or numerous StackOverflow posts discussed this problem, which is why I posted my question.  I'll assume you're having a bad day and hope it turns around for you.

Comment: you didn't point what exactly  is null in your question ... anyway, yeah, i was thinking about this question and now I'm seeing that it's not answering your question

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398855/cannot-read-data-in-firebase-database-as-list) by Frank van Puffelen is the answer, well rather it gave me an elegant solution.

Instead of doing a for loop based on the .size() of the returned list he recommended iterating through the children of dataSnapshot.getChildren().  Like this:

```
for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    poiList.add(child.getValue(POI.class));
}
```

I assume this is the pattern the good folks on the Firebase team would recommend.  Just be careful using the size method on Firebase dataSnapshot objects.